# Email From Website Not Generating html?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using this code to send emails from my website (Taken from here https://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/scripts-and-programming-languages-c85099/aspnet-c39624/send-an-e-mail-using-aspnet-a604246.html)

```
//create the mail message
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
//set the FROM address
mail.From = new MailAddress(from);
//set the RECIPIENTS
mail.To.Add(to);
//enter a SUBJECT
mail.Subject = subject;
//Enter the message BODY
mail.Body = body;
//set the mail server (default should be smtp.1and1.com)
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.1and1.com");
//Enter your full e-mail address and password
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin@blank.com", "Password");
//send the message 
smtp.Send(mail);
```

The emails being sent are not generating the html. So instead of a link showing up it will have the actual code for a link ect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your comments on every line....I wouldn't include those in the real code if I were you. If the line is self explanatory, no need to comment. You're basically rehashing what the code already says. I'd only comment it if the line is unclear or unexpected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the following line:

```
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
```